# COBOL-DB2 -803 equivalent in java

Tags: java, cobol

Cobol : [INSERT CODE]

```
 EVALUATE SQLCODE
           WHEN +000
            ...
           WHEN -803
             ...
           WHEN OTHER
             ...
       END-EVALUATE.
```

This code evaluates SQLCODE and duplicate entry is handled here by -803.  A -803 error is AN INSERTED OR UPDATED VALUE IS INVALID BECAUSE THE INDEX IN INDEX SPACE indexspace-name CONSTRAINS COLUMNS OF THE TABLE SO NO TWO ROWS CAN CONTAIN DUPLICATE VALUES IN THOSE COLUMNS. RID OF EXISTING ROW IS X record-id.

In other words a duplicate key error.

In java , I usually do the same by  firing a select query and look for the entry existence into database and if it does not exist then I insert the record.

Is there any other way to handle -803 situation in Java?

Comment: This is the usual way of handling a duplicate key error in COBOL.  You can prevent this type of error by doing a SELECT before the INSERT.  If the SELECT returns a row, do an UPDATE instead.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: SELECT before INSERT can break due to a race condition (unless you have repeatable reads, which introduces a whole other dimension of problems). Handling the Database error is still required.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Ok, mostly prevent duplicate key errors.  I'm wondering if someone coded the -803 error as the "ok, update" indicator in the OP's code.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726856/find-if-an-sqlexception-was-thrown-because-of-a-duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, you want to catch the `SQLException` and test for the error code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = ...;
try
{
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    if (e.getErrorCode() == -803)
    {
        // handle duplicate entry
    }
    else
    {
        // handle other errors
    }
}
```

Note, this code is DB2 specific as -803 is a vendor-specific error code.